# PHP PDO Error while executing and inserting in cleardb

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, cleardb

Hi I am getting error during the execution of PDO prepare statement. My local development works fine but when I try to insert to cleardb in cloud this error occur:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1142 INSERT command denied to user 'b2218f51d4a66e'@'191.235.136.58' for table 'user'' in /var/www/php1/CRUD.php:52

```
    function create_User($firstname, $lastname, $username, $password, $address, $city, $zip, $country, $email) {
    global $dbh;
    $this->password = $password;
    $token = md5($this->salt1 . $this->password . $this->salt2);

    $this->sth = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO `Php_Project`.`User`
(        
userName,
passWord,
    create_DateStamp,
e_mail)

    VALUES
    (               
            :username,
    :token,
            NOW(),
    :email
    );
```

');

```
    $this->sth->bindParam(':username', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $this->sth->bindParam(':token', $token, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $this->sth->bindParam(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    if ($this->sth->execute()) {
        $this->message = "true";
    } else {
        $this->message = "false";
    }

    if ($this->message == "true") {
        $userId = $dbh->lastInsertId();
        $this->sth = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO `Php_Project`.`user_Detail`
(    
firstName,
lastname,
adress,
zip,
city,
country,
userId)

    VALUES
    (       
        :firstname,
        :lastname,
        :address,
        :zip,
        :city,
        :country,
        :userId
    );');

        $this->sth->bindParam(':firstname', $firstname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $this->sth->bindParam(':lastname', $lastname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $this->sth->bindParam(':address', $address, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $this->sth->bindParam(':zip', $zip, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $this->sth->bindParam(':city', $city, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $this->sth->bindParam(':country', $country, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $this->sth->bindParam(':userId', $userId, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        if ($this->sth->execute()) {
            $this->message = true;
        } else {
            $this->message = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a permissions problem. Your database user has the `INSERT` permission for the table on your development server but not on your production server, so you'll need to change the user permissions using `GRANT` on your production server.

Comment: If so why does this query works fine from mysql workbench:INSERT INTO `as_754979fd4dcbfcb`.`user`
(`userId`,
`userName`,
`passWord`,
`create_DateStamp`,
`update_DateStamp`,
`e_mail`)
VALUES
(default,
"1111",
"2222",
now(),
default,
"abc@123.com");

Comment: Are you logging in to Workbench as the user `b2218f51d4a66e`? Also, please bear in mind that the second part of the user identifier also counts (for example, 'b2218f51d4a66e'@'191.235.136.58' isn't the same as 'b2218f51d4a66e'@'%', the latter allowing access from any host as opposed to one single host)